# What it means that extending Exceptions facilitates the identification

Tags: php, exception

> When a generic exception is thrown in your application, you have to
>   read through the stack trace to determine where and what caused that
>   exception to be thrown.
>
> (...) By custom exceptions, we’ve made it easy to identify from which part
>   of our application the exception comes from.

I don't get it. With default Exception stack trace indicates me line where exception was originally thrown.

```
function foo($i)
{
    if ($i<0){
        throw new Exception("<0");
    }
    if ($i>0){
        throw new Exception(">0");
    }

}

try {
    foo(1);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    throw $e;
}
```

So how do custom Exceptions facilitate the identification?

Comment: Firstly, the name of the exception will be different. Also, it allows for easy checking of an exceptions type. In some respects it's not a massive difference at all but it does come with benefits especially in bigger applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a generic exception like `Exception`, you'll have to read through the stack trace to understand what's going on. Custom exceptions can convey this information in their type, allowing you to programatically address the issue:

```
function foo($i)
{
    if ($i<0){
        throw new NegativeInputException($i);
    }
    if ($i>0){
        throw new PositiveInputException($i);
    }

}

try {
    foo(getFromUser());
} catch (NegativeInputException $e) {
    echo "why would you input a negative number?";
} catch (PositiveInputException $e) {
    echo "why would you input a positive number?";
}
```

Comment: so kind of: message of exception is dedicated for user and is just happy communique, and descriptive name of custom exception class is for developer.

Comment: @user6827096 descriptive name + hierarchy is for the developer. If there's any case you'd want to treat NegativeInputException and PositiveInputException in the same way, you could have them both extend InputException, and catch that.